# How to create the click event of a button which is dynamically created by reading the xml file in wpf?

Tags: xml, wpf, button, dynamic, stackpanel

I am a newbie to wpf and i am doing some poc on wpf controls.I have created the buttons dynamically by reading from my xml file and i placed the buttons inside a stackpanel.i want to write the click event of the button by clicking on it and i wrote a click event which gives all the button names inside the stack panel but what i want is i want to get the respective button name when i click.

My XML FILE:

```
<root>
  <Project Name="FundsCrossReferences" Label ="SMA Model Management" LibraryName="SMAMC" ClassName="" Roles="">
  </Project>
  <Project Name="SMAFI" Label ="SMAFI" LibraryName="SMAFI" ClassName="" Roles="">    
  </Project> 
 </root>
```

My window.xaml.cs file

```
private void windowloaded()
        {         
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (XElement level1Element in XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\Trial\XMLFile.xml").Elements("Project"))
            {

                    result.AppendLine(level1Element.Attribute("Name").Value+"/");

            }
             List<string> addnames = new List<string>();
             string[] stringArray = result.ToString().Split('/').ToArray();
            stringArray = stringArray.Take(stringArray.Count() - 1).ToArray();
            foreach (var arrayname in stringArray)
            {
                var names = arrayname.Replace("\r\n", "");
                addnames.Add(names);
            }
            List<string> list = addnames.ToList();
            foreach(var buttoname in list)
            {
                var newButton = new Button() { Name= buttoname,Height=39,Foreground=Brushes.Black,Content=buttoname};
                this.mainpanel.Children.Add(newButton);
            }     
         }
```

My Window.xaml:
 `<StackPanel x:Name="mainpanel"></StackPanel>`

Kindly help me with the click event of buttons or the name of the button which is clicked inside the stackpanel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF How to know the current button pressed among multiple buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566323/wpf-how-to-know-the-current-button-pressed-among-multiple-buttons)

Comment: Instead of creating Buttons in code and programatically putting them into a StackPanel, you would usually use an ItemsControl with a Button in its ItemTemplate. The Button's Command property would be bound to an ICommand property in the item class. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: @anjalinsneha: Just hook up a click event handler in the `foreach` loop: `newButton.Click += Your_Handler;`

Comment: Thank you so much @mm8 .My problem is solved and i'm getting the solution.Thanks a lot.as i was studying on this i was struggling a lot ,with one line you just solved .Very helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just hook up a click event handler in the `foreach` loop:

```
newButton.Click += Your_Handler;
```